# Exercise about voltage thresholds of logical port

Tags: voltage, port

I don't understand how professor resolves this exercise!

I have two connected logical port and I want to calculate the time of transition from low to high for example. 
[image]

In the solution, the minimum time is the time to reach \$V_{il}\$ and max time is the time to reach \$V_{ih}\$.
My doubt is this: in the voltages between \$V_{il}\$ and \$V_{ih}\$, the second port, for the definition of \$V_{il}\$ don't understand high (I guess) because it is a zone of transition, so, why it is the minimum time of transition from low to high?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it takes time to change the voltage, the **minimum transition time** will occur when your signal has to make the smallest possible change in voltage. If the signal starts as a logic '0' then its maximum voltage is \$V_{IL}\$. The smallest voltage that will be recognized as a logic '1' is \$V_{IH}\$. So, the smallest possible **voltage** change from **logic** low to **logic** high is from \$V_{IL}\$ to \$V_{IH}\$ and the minimum transition **time** is the time required for the signal voltage to make that change.

Answer (score 0):

When the input voltage is between Vil and Vih, the response of the circuit is undefined.  It may be interpreted as either high or low.  Most inputs will transition at some point in between.  However, there is likely a point where both transistors are on, and you get shoot-through current.  This can damage the input, and in some cases, double edging may occur...this is why rise times on clock inputs are critical.  It's unavoidable that the input voltage will be in this range at some point during the transition, but observing the rise time specs will prevent undesired behavior.